# Spring data JPA - Many to Many

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I have two entity classes, **match** and **player**, with **@ManyToMany** relationships. I have a *table matchplayer* with fields matchid and playerid(foreign key mapped from above classes).
I need to remove a player and the foreign key in matchplayer provides an error. As I don't have an entity class and repository for matchplayer, how can I do this?

Is there any feature like *orphanremoval* that works with @ManyToMany?

Comment: Nope, there isn't one. You need to actually iterate over all matches associated to the player and call `match.getPlayers().remove(player)` in the same transaction in which you are attempting to delete the player themselves